# Symfony 4 - Can't persist cascade my entity (error : A new entity was found through the relationship)

Tags: php, symfony, entity, cascade, persist

in my symfony 4 project I've :

**GroupeValidateurs.php:**

```
/**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Validateur", mappedBy="groupeValidateurs", orphanRemoval=true, cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"ordre" = "ASC"})
     */
    private $validateurs;
```

**Validateur.php:**

```
/**
 * Ordre de validation
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation\SortablePosition
 */
private $ordre;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="validateurs")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $validateur;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\GroupeValidateurs", inversedBy="validateurs")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $groupeValidateurs;
```

And **User.php**

```
/**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Validateur", mappedBy="validateur", orphanRemoval=true, cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $validateurs;
```

When I'm on my GroupeValidateurs page :

[image]

If I add a new "Validateur" (in the example, I will add KELLEN Russel), and I submit, I've this :

> HTTP 500 Internal Server Error A new entity was found through the
>   relationship 'App\Entity\GroupeValidateurs#validateurs' that was not
>   configured to cascade persist operations for entity: KELLEN Russel. To
>   solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on
>   this unknown entity or configure cascade persist this association in
>   the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}).

According the error message, I added `cascade={"persist", "remove"})` in `GroupeValidateurs#validateurs` but the problem is same

Can someone help me please ?

UPDATE : When I edit my "GroupeValidateurs" to add new "Validateur", I've my function service :

```
/**
     * Edite un groupe validateurs
     *
     * @param array $oldUsers
     * @param array $newUsers
     * @param GroupeValidateurs $nouveauGroupe
     * @return array $flash message $flash
     */
    public function editGroupeValidateurs($oldUsers, $newUsers, GroupeValidateurs $nouveauGroupe)
    {
        if ($this->isValidGroupeValidateurs($nouveauGroupe)) {

            $comparaison = $this->compareBeforeAfter($oldUsers, $newUsers);

            $this->updateValidationAbsences($nouveauGroupe, $this->getAbsencesFromGroupe($nouveauGroupe));
            $this->isValidatorOtherGroup($comparaison["validateursSupprimes"], $nouveauGroupe);
            $this->traiterRoleSuperValidateurEdit($oldUsers, $newUsers, $nouveauGroupe);
            $this->traiterRoleChefServiceEdit($oldUsers, $newUsers, $nouveauGroupe);
            $this->setRolesValidateurs($nouveauGroupe);

            foreach($nouveauGroupe->getValidateurs() as $validateur)
            {
                $this->manager->persist($validateur);
            }

            $this->manager->persist($nouveauGroupe);
            $this->manager->flush();
```

So I make a loop to persist all "Validateur" of the "GroupeValidateurs"

Comment: Can i view your code where you make a persist ?

Comment: Yes, I updated my first post with the function

Comment: It's okay, I used $manager->flush() on a method of my edit function, so, it was a problem. Thanks !